# Standard normal distribution vs Unit normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, terminology, z-score

Are the Standard normal distribution and Unit normal distribution describe exactly the same? Or they describe different things?

Comment: This is readily answered by Googling both phrases.  In fact, the extract from the second hit when I Googled "Unit normal distribution" states "If μ = 0 and σ = 1, then the distribution is called the standard normal distribution or the unit normal distribution,..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment by @whuber, this would have been solved fast by searching the internet. And the answer is **YES**, they are the same.